# How to host static react application in subdomain?

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I want to server static react application on nginx on a subdomain
Currently, I test it on my local machine.

http://local-dev/app

After I configured nginx and docker. I could access the static sites in the subdomain in my local machine. (I've updated local-dev to point to localhost)

The assets path is not right, so I followed some tutorials and modify index.js and package.json to have basename which
tells react that this application is going to run on a subdomain.

And I could only got blank page but seeing resources loaded correctly in the developer console.

What's going on?
Any formal/ official guideline talking about subdomain deployment?

Thanks a lot.

## index.js

```
      <Provider store={store}>
          <BrowserRouter basename={'/app'}>
              <App />
          </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
```

## Package.json

```
  "homepage": "https://local.dev/app",
```

## Nginx

```
server {
  server_name local.dev;
  location /app {
    root   /var/www/app;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

## Docker

```
version: '3.6'
services:
    nginx-app:
      image: nginx:${NGINX_VERSION:-latest}
      container_name: nginx-app
      ports:
        - '80:80'
      volumes:
        - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        - /react-app/build:/var/www/app
```

Comment: Where are you hosting this websites? Is this local?

Comment: Do you have external scripts or linked css files in your index.html?

Comment: @ViniciusKatata  in my local machine, everything was working with nginx ,docker, react. Until i put subdomain...

Comment: You should treat the same way, there is no diff